# Is Alan from "The Amazing World of Gumball" really a good guy?

Tags: character-motivation, character-development, amazing-world-of-gumball

During most episodes he appears in, Alan Keane is portrayed as a good "person", always striving to take care of others to the point of sacrificing himself in multiple occasions. This has always been a plot point, with Gumball often getting annoyed by his ability to never lose his temper.

The episode [The Saint](http://theamazingworldofgumball.wikia.com/wiki/The_Saint) revolves around this idea: Gumball tries to make Alan lose his temper with a series of increasingly cruel "pranks" (including selling his family to a clown to be used for balloon arts). Yet, to Gumball dismay Alan keeps calm during the whole episode. In the end, it seems like Alan finally gets annoyed but we soon discover he is just pretending to make Gumball happy (he even says "It is nice to make you happy" as soon as Gumball leaves).

This has for long given the impression that the character is a sort of Mary Sue parody, too good to be true.

Until the episode [The Vision](http://theamazingworldofgumball.wikia.com/wiki/The_Vision) came out..
This episode completely rewrites Alan character, turning him into a sort of "righteous tyrant" wannabe, ready to do anything to "make people happy". His "smile camp" is basically a reforming prison, where all "sad" people would be sent to learn to "become happy".
At the end of the episode, he start planning world domination, at which point Gumball blows him up him with a needle.

After that episode, there were no further sign of the character real motivation, so I am wondering if that episode was meant to be an onetime weird joke or if the Alan portrayed in The Vision is the real Alan. Is there any official claim about that?

As a side notice, in the episode "The Night", which was aired **before** "The vision", we see an imagine of what Alan is dreaming. This image.

[image]

Maybe The Vision was a follow up joke to that dream?